# Serialising predicates over wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, generics, predicate

I have a WCF service that exposes a bunch of methods that return business objects. Under its hood it has a nice repository layer that uses interface methods like this:

```
IEnumerable<User> GetUsers(Func<User, bool> predicate);
```

So if I want all users within a given role I can do:

```
var plebs = GetUsers(u => u.Roles.Contains(plebRole));
```

Now I want to expose this any-filter-can-be-satisfied thinking over the WCF interface. The WCF api needs to be accessible to non .Net clients so I want to use (relatively) simple types.

I have a Filter object that holds a property name and and value:

```
[DataContract] public class Filter {
    [DataMember] public string Property { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

So now I can expose a WCF method like this:

```
IEnumerable<User> GetUsers(IEnumerable<Filter> filters);
```

Then I can build predicates based on what comes in, in the clients filters. Now it gets messy:

```
private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetPredicate<T>(Filter filter)
{
  var knownPredicates = GetKnownPredicates<T>(filter.Value);
  var t = typeof(T);
  return knownPredicates.ContainsKey(t) && knownPredicates[t].ContainsKey(filter.Property)
           ? knownPredicates[t][filter.Property]
           : True<T>();
}

private static Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<T, bool>>>> GetKnownPredicates<T>(string value)
{
  // ReSharper disable PossibleNullReferenceException
  return new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<T, bool>>>>
  {
    {
      typeof (User), new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<T, bool>>>
      {
        { "Forename", x => (x as User).Forename == value },
        { "IsAdult", x => (x as User).IsAdult.ToString() == value },
        ...
      }
    },
    {
      typeof (Group), new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<T, bool>>>
      {
        { "Name", x => (x as Group).Name == value },
        ...
      }
    },
    ...
  };
  // ReSharper restore PossibleNullReferenceException
}
```

Until I started writing the GetKnownPredicates method, the code didn't really stink. Now it does. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be super-fancy you could use the [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx) class to dynamically build a predicate based on the passed-in filter. You know the type that you're going to search, so all you need to do is to [create a property expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd294147.aspx) using Filter.Property and then a constant expression with Filter.Value. Use them to compose an equal expression and you're near the finish line.

Getting used to composing expressions can be a pain, but the debugger is really helpful and will show you the code for your expression as you compose it, so dive in and try it out!

Comment: Of course, you'll need to consider security, since you may not want to let end users query any property of your classes. Maybe attribute properties with a custom "OK to Filter" attribute that you check before creating the filter.

Comment: Cool, this is the route I want to explore. I'm not concerned about security because I do have an auth token in the request object and I have a mechanism for deciding whether or not to process the request.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely **no way** you could get your `Func<User, bool>` across the wire. *This expression is stored and will be jitted and will live in the client side world.*

Remember, what you are basically doing is to compile an anonymous client-side function by using `u => u.Roles.Contains(plebRole)`. So you would be getting some users that you will filter then later at client side.

Comment: That's all true, but there are often several ways to skin cats. I don't literally mean to serialise the predicate. I've already done that with `IEnumerable<Filter>`. I could add properties to filter to specify things like operators and comparison types. The real issue is how to convert the filters to predicates without specifying each and every possible property and comparison type (things like `StartsWith()` and dealing with collections like `user.Roles`, etc...).